# Is it possible to individually update each module using update.php?

Tags: updating

I am trying to update the reCAPTCHA module (which is installed on sites/all/modules) in Drupal 7. I could see other 3 modules which have pending updates. Is it possible to individually update each module using update.php?

Comment: What do you mean by update? It means downloading the updates module and place it i modules?

Or just running update.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can't update single module using "update.php".
You can update single module if you installed drush.

List all available modules (except core) with below command.

> drush pm-list --type=module --no-core --status=enabled

Update specified module only.

> drush up 'module-name'

or

> drush pm-update --no-core "module_name"

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/security-update-module.html to update single module using Drush and inbuilt functionality.

If you are using composer then run below command.

```
    composer update drupal/<module_name> --with-dependencies
```